# What is the difference between the SalesChannelRepository and the EntityRepository repositories?

Tags: shopware

In Shopware 6 you have 2 types of auto generated repositories.
Those who implement the `\Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelRepositoryInterface` and those who implement the `\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface`.

What is the difference between them and when to use which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should use the EntityRepositoryInterface for "admin" work, for example to update, import or delete data.

The SalesChannelRepositoryInterface should be used every time a SalesChannelContext is available. For instance the product instance returns SalesChannelProductEntity a extension of the Product Entity, with more data.

Comment: I guess the saleschannelproductentity also returns the right data for the sales channel, i.e the proper translation and so on?

Comment: Yes, it contains a translated note with for example the correct translated name of the Product for your current SalesChannel.